# Generating a number set that reduces the chances of entering the wrong (but existing) number

Tags: statistics

I'm looking to generate a set of distinct, 6 digit numbers (no more than 100,000 right now). These numbers are printed on devices in the format `123-456` and are used to identify those devices.

A user will type in the number (numeric keypad on a phone) in order to then perform an action on that device.

It's possible that a user will mistype the number resulting in one of two situations:

1. They mistype the number in front of them but the number they type doesn't exist and we throw an error informing them the device doesn't exist, try again.
2. They mistype the number in-front of them but the number they type does exist (a device they are not looking at) and the action is then performed against the wrong device.

We are trying to figure out whether you can reduce the probability of the second outcome by generating a set of numbers that have "enough spread".

For example, it seems logical (although i might be wrong) that generating sequential numbers would increase the chances of mistyping a number but landing on one that does exist vs a set of randomly generated numbers (assuming that the set of generated numbers is less than the largest potential size of the set). As you increase the set of generated numbers the probability of outcome two must also increase.

We also thought about using a checksum but now suspect that this only helps us identify when the number doesn't exist... which we would know anyway.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: You're basically talking about "error-correcting codes".

Comment: You need to specify what kind of 'mistyping' you have in mind. If I'm going to make one of your typos, do I get one number wrong (`128 456` instead of `123 456`), do I transpose two adjacent numbers (`213 456`), or do I just type at random (`932,721`)? Your idea of 'spread' seems to imply you have specific substitutions or transpositions in mind. // 'Typing at random' would be easiest to answer.

Comment: Have you looked into error-correcting codes yet, Michael?

Comment: Earth to Michael, come in, please.

Comment: Hi folks! Thanks for the input so far and apologies for the delay in getting back to you. @BruceET good point! The numbers are being read and input on a mobile numeric keyboard so we imagine the first two scenarios you describe, rather than completely random.

Comment: @GerryMyerson we did look at error correction. We looked more at checksums (using the Luhn algorithm). We haven't proved it but it seemed intuitive that by generating a set of numbers between `100,000` and `999,999` that pass the Luhn checksum we would then have numbers where, if a user mistyped that number (as above) it was more likely they would land on a number that doesn't exist within our set than one that does. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't know – I'm not familiar with the Luhn checksum – but I reckon any checksum is a way to implement an error-correcting (or at least -detecting) code.